# Implementing a dynamic search bar with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend, mern

```js
    import Link from 'next/link';
    import renderHTML from 'react-render-html';
    import { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';
    import { listSearch } from '../../actions/blog';
    import '../../static/css/styles.css'
    
    
    import './Search';
    
    
    
    const Search = () => {
        const [values, setValues] = useState({
            search: undefined,
            results: [],
            searched: false,
            message: '',
    
        });
    
        const { search, results, searched, message } = values;
    
        const searchSubmit =e=> {
            e.preventDefault();
           
            listSearch({ search}).then(data => {
                setValues({ ...values, results: data, searched: true, message: `${data.length} blogs found` });
            });
        };
    
    
        
        const handleChange = e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setValues({ ...values, search: e.target.value, searched: false, results: [] });
        };
    
        
        
        const searchedBlogs = (results = []) => {
            return (
                <div className="jumbotron bg-white ">
                    {message && <p className=" text-muted font-italic">{message}</p>}
    
                    {results.map((blog, i) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={i}>
                                <Link href={`/blogs/${blog.slug}`}>
                                    <a className="text-primary">{blog.title}</a>
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            );
        };

    
        const searchForm = () => (
            <form onSubmit={searchSubmit}>
                <div className="row">
    
                   <div className="col-md-4 buttonIn">
                        <input id="search" type="search" className="form-control" 
                               placeholder="Search blogs" onChange={handleChange} />
                          {/* <button id="search-button"  type="submit">
                                <img style={{width: 20, height: 20}} 
                                      src='../../static/images/search.png' />
                            </button> */}
    
                    </div> 
                </div>
    
            </form>
        );
    
        return (
            <div >
                <div className="pl-2 pt-2 pb-2 pr-2">{searchForm()}</div>
     
                {searched && <div > {searchedBlogs(results)} </div>}
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default Search;
```

I am not able to implement dynamic search functionality in the above code, in `handleChange()` function `e.target.value` is only taking a the first value of the input element.
The problem is that I'm only to fetch the first character and not the entire string.
In `searchSubmit()` function, I'm able to retrieve the search results, though not in real-time as I type in the query in the search bar.
What changes can I make to implement the above functionality?

Comment: why are using single `object` as a state, bcz i don't see any need, make separate states it'll be much easier to handle........ and you want to search as u type is that your requirement?

Comment: Yeah as I type in the query, the search results should come up in realtime